# How do I specify the json field to display in my Xamarain List View?

Tags: c#, json, azure, xamarin

I have my xamarin forms application returning an observable collection from my Azure database called `Users`.  Once this is returned it wipes out the `ListView` and replaces it with the returned json collection.

Whilst it returns my data without any problems the issue is that it seems to be only showing the top level of information without going down into `id` and `FirstName`. For example

[image: 01]
The `Users.ReplaceRange(coffees);` clears the listview and outputs the returned collection.  What is outputs is `CoffeeCups.users` What I need to do is show `FirstName` which is one tier down from `CoffeeCup.users` for example

[image: 02]

So how can I ensure my list displays the correct field from my returned json collection?

For reference here is the code for my list view.

**CoffeesPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CoffeeCups;assembly=CoffeeCups"
    x:Class="CoffeeCups.CoffeesPage"
    Title="Cups Of Coffee">         
            <ListView 
                Grid.Row="1"                
                IsGroupingEnabled="true"
                HasUnevenRows ="true"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"
                IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
                IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
                RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadCoffeesCommand}"
                x:Name="ListViewCoffees">
             <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>    
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
             </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>              
</ContentPage>
```

For reference:

**users.cs**

```
using System;

namespace CoffeeCups
{
    public class users
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**AzureServices.cs**

```
       public class AzureService
        {

            public MobileServiceClient Client { get; set; } = null;

            IMobileServiceSyncTable<users> userTable;

            public async Task Initialize()
            {
                var appUrl = "https://myurl.azurewebsites.net";

                //Create our client
                Client = new MobileServiceClient(appUrl);

                //InitialzeDatabase for path
                var path = "syncstore.db";
                path = Path.Combine(MobileServiceClient.DefaultDatabasePath, path);

                //setup our local sqlite store and intialize our table
                var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(path);

                //Define table
                store.DefineTable<users>();

                //Initialize SyncContext
                await Client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);

                //Get our sync table that will call out to azure
                userTable = Client.GetSyncTable<users>();
            }

            public async Task SyncCoffee()
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
                        return;                   
                    await userTable.PullAsync("allUsers", userTable.CreateQuery());    
                    await Client.SyncContext.PushAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Unable to sync coffees, that is alright as we have offline capabilities: " + ex);
                }

            }

            public async Task<IEnumerable<users>> GetUsers()
            {
                //Initialize & Sync
                await Initialize();
                await SyncCoffee();

                return await userTable.OrderBy(c => c.FirstName).ToEnumerableAsync(); ;

            }
        }
```

**CoffeesViewModel.cs**

```
 async Task ExecuteLoadCoffeesCommandAsync()
        {
            try 
            {
                LoadingMessage = "Loading Coffees...";
                IsBusy = true;
                var coffees = await azureService.GetUsers();    
                Users.ReplaceRange(coffees);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("OH NO!" + ex);
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Sync Error", "Unable to sync coffees, you may be offline", "OK");
            } 
            finally 
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }
```

**CoffeesPage.xaml.cs**

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            if (vm.Users.Count == 0)
                vm.LoadCoffeesCommand.Execute(null);
            else
            {                 
                vm.LoadCoffeesCommand.Execute(null);
            }            
        }
```

Comment: what is the type of Users?

Comment: @Jason `Users` is an Observable Collection as follows: `public ObservableRangeCollection<users> Users { get; } = new ObservableRangeCollection<users>();`

Comment: please post the code for your users class

Comment: @Jason I have updated my original question to include some code blocks for reference. Thanks

Comment: based on what you posted your binding should work as-is.  Where do you initialize Users, and are you perhaps re-initializing it somewhere after the initial binding is done?

Comment: @Jason I have expanded my question further to include more code.  Obviously the none essentials have been removed for brevity but the core functionality is there.

Comment: I don't see any code that initializes Users.  What exactly is the symptom you are seeing?  Does the list just not get updated at all, or is the binding broken (the list is updated, but the cell does not have the correct value)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136966/discussion-between-yanayaya-and-jason).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and as I suspected it is in fact something very simple.  If we take a look at the `ListView` we can see that there is an option called `IsGroupingEnabled` which is set to `True` .

I now know that this option will in fact just group up any returned json collection into itself effectivly bundling the results into a single entry that you can expose for interactions with the user.

Switching this option to false (as it's not something I need) allowed the bound lables to return what was specified.